# Hyperbolic final probability density function Opencv

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, opencv

Hello guys i have a run time error and i dont know maybe something with wrong number input? i thought i would ask some help

maybe something is out of range in `t[x]=gmin*pow(gmax/gmin, factor);`??

```
void image::hhyper(const char* path)
{
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage(path);
    IplImage* out = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3 );

    h = img->height;
    w = img->width;
    step = img->widthStep;
    channels = img->nChannels;
    data = (uchar *)img->imageData;
    newdata = (uchar *)out->imageData;

    int gmin=20;
    int gmax=200;

    double sum=0;
    double t[256];
    double factor;

    for(int a=0; a<h; a++){
        for(int b=0; b<w; b++){
            for(int k=0; k<3; k++){
                newdata[i*step+j*channels+k]=data[i*step+j*channels+k];
            }
        }
    }

    for(int x=0; x<256; x++){
       sum+=table[x];
       factor=sum/(h*w);
       t[x]=gmin*pow(gmax/gmin, factor);
    }

    for(int a=0; a<h; a++){
        for(int b=0; b<w; b++){
            for(int k=0; k<3; k++){
                newdata[i*step+j*channels+k]=t[(int)data[i*step+j*channels+k]];
       }
        }
    }

    cvNamedWindow("out");
    cvNamedWindow("in");
    cvShowImage("in",img);
    cvShowImage("out",out);
    system("pause");
}
```

and here is my header

```
  class image
 {
public:
image();
const char* path;
void hhyper(const char*);
void histo(const char*);
IplImage* DrawHistogram(CvHistogram *hist, float scaleX, float scaleY);
int h,w,step,channels,i,j,;
int table[256];
uchar *data, *newdata;
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: natve the arrays are too big? any ideas guys?

Comment: Have you tried running through the code in a debugger?

Comment: yes and its always stops working...i think some value is over the borders or smthg similar

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this

```
newdata[i*step+j*channels+k] = t[(int)data[i*step+j*channels+k]];
```

should be

```
newdata[i*step+j*channels+k] = t[(uchar)data[i*step+j*channels+k]];
```

Comment: hmm no doesnt change the result :/

Comment: ok found solution i just had to change some symbols...thank you for your help though